# Is there a way to include forward headers for std::filesystem?

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++14, header-files

In the same way that iostreams has the forward-include header `#include<iosfwd>` a header with declarations only, I assumed that Filesystems would have one too. However I couldn't find one.

I have a class that declares a single member function with `filesystem::path const&` as argument and it seems an overkill to bring the whole of `#include<experimental/filesystem>` just to get `path`.

```
#include<experimental/filsystem_fwd> // or #include<experimental/filesystem/path/*only*/>
...
struct A{
  ...
  void save(std::experimental::filesystem::path const& p);
}
```

Comment: Sad, but seems to be no ... The whole library is in the big header `<filesystem>` (or `<experimental/filesystem>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there such a header? No.

Could you make such a header? Also, no. [[namespace.std]/1 tells us:](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.std)

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified.

Since any forward declarations of `std` namespace things would have to be part of the `std` namespace, you can't do that. You're allowed to write template specializations, and there are certain cases where you're allowed to poke at `std` itself. But declaring `std::filesystem::*` isn't something you can do.

Comment: Doing a forward declaration of `path` didn't even occur to me. And now that you mention it, it doesn't even work because `path` is(can be) a typedef of an implementation detail `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path`. So the filesystem library doesn't compile after `namespace std{namespace experimental{namespace filesystem{
class path;
}}}` with a message `bits/fs_dir.h:94:36 error: reference to ‘path’ is ambiguous...`.